# If I fall from a very high place and do crits, will the crits be higher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I fall from a really high place and then do crits on a player, will the crits do more damage to the player? Assuming that we have Feather Falling 4...

I am curious about this and I've searched everywhere if the crits get modified depending on the jump's height. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

**No**. Critical hits deal 150% base damage regardless of how far you fall.

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Critical_hits): "[a critical hit] deals 150% of the equipped item's base damage (before enchantments or armor are applied)."

If you want to dive into the source code ([courtesy of MCP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/is-there-a-way-to-see-minecrafts-source-code)), like I did, this is even more clear. Kind of. A little.

In `EntityPlayer.java`, inside the function `attackTargetEntityWithCurrentItem(Entity targetEntity)` (which does precisely what it says on the tin), we can find the code that controls how much damage the player deals to other entities. The critical hit check happens on lines 1330-1335:

```
...
boolean var5 = this.fallDistance > 0.0F && !this.onGround && !this.isOnLadder() && !this.isInWater() && !this.isPotionActive(Potion.blindness) && this.ridingEntity == null && targetEntity instanceof EntityLivingBase;
if (var5 && var2 > 0.0F)
{
    var2 *= 1.5F;
}
...
```

`var2` is the base damage to be dealt before enchantments are applied. `var5` is a boolean, set to true if the player is falling, not on the ground, not on a ladder, etc. The code never checks how far the player has fallen in any capacity other than to see if the player is falling at all.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Critical hits always deal 150% base damage.

> The attack deals 150% of the equipped item's base damage (before enchantments or armor are applied).

source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Critical_hits)