# Are players considered mobs by the game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft when we refer to a Mob we refer to monsters and animals and thus when something said it deals x damage to mobs it's normally used in context to the player attacking.

However in Multiplayer there are multiple players. so i am wondering, in terms of the game are Players a Mob?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No**. The player is a living entity, but not a mob.

From a terminology standpoint, the word "mob" usually refers to hostile, non-player creatures.

In Minecraft's source code (courtesy of [MCP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52441/is-there-a-way-to-see-minecrafts-source-code)), we can see for ourselves how the game classifies different entities. The player class `EntityPlayer` extends `EntityLivingBase`, whereas all hostile creatures extend `EntityMob`. The player is not considered a mob in the game code either.

However, in many cases, things that apply to mobs apply to all living creatures. When you see that something deals x damage to mobs, that really means it deals x damage to living creatures. A diamond sword deals as much damage to a skeleton as it does an unarmored player.

Comment: `EntityMob` extends `EntityCreature` which extends `EntityLiving` which extends `EntityLivingBase`. `EntityPlayer` extends `EntityLivingBase`.

Answer (score -4):

Actually mob stands for mobile entity so as the other person said the players are not entities it is basically referring to everything else in the game that is alive since they are entities that can move so basically mobile entity.

Comment: So you happen to have a source for this information?